# Capacitor on Android fails with error: "ERR_SDK_PACKAGE_NOT_FOUND: SDK package not found by location: D:\Android_SDK_HOME\platform-tools."

Tags: android, ionic-framework, sdk, capacitor

I wanted to run my Ionic/Capacitor app via `npx cap run android` on an Android emulator. Nevertheless, the process got killed with the following error:

```
× Deploying app-debug.apk to Pixel_3_API_30 - failed!
[error] ADBs is unresponsive after 5000ms, killing server and retrying...
    ERR_SDK_PACKAGE_NOT_FOUND: SDK package not found by location: 
    D:\Android_SDK_HOME\platform-tools.

    More details for this error may be available online:

            https://github.com/ionic-team/native-run/wiki/Android-Errors
```

The correct location of the platform tools would be: **D:\Android_SDK_HOME\Sdk\platform-tools**.
My ANDROID_SDK_HOME variable is set to **D:\Android_SDK_HOME**, but when i change it to **D:\Android_SDK_HOME\Sdk**, this still results in the same error.

Does anyone know how/from wherre Capacitor accesses the SDK location, and how i can configure it?

Comment: The solution can be found here: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/discussions/4828#discussioncomment-999428

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I have android-studio in /opt/android-studio.

My SDK in `$HOME/Android/Sdk`.

Error message `ERR_SDK_PACKAGE_NOT_FOUND` said it was looking for the SDK in  `/opt/android-studio/platform-tools`.

That directory was not there!

My solution: `ln -s $HOME/Android/Sdk/platform-tools /opt/android-studio`

Then, the command `native-run android` --list worked.

Answer (score 0):

#### My situation:

For me the solution provided here didn't work:
https://github.com/ionic-team/native-run/wiki/Android-Errors#err_sdk_package_not_found

I always used android studio to start the emulator before I did `npx cap run android`. (e.g. I started the Pixel 2 API 31, see it listed in the list in the image below)

[image]

#### Solution:

But then, when I simply selected the first option `Google sdk_gphone64_x86_64 (emulator-5554)` then it worked and shipped & started the app onto my Pixel 2 31 API. strange but it works. This is actually the name my Pixel 2 31 API phone has, when I go under device settings. NOTE: this option will only show up if I started some kind of emulator before running `npx cap run android`

#### Additional Info:

I had this error:
× Deploying app-debug.apk to Pixel_4_API_33 - failed!
[error] ERR_SDK_PACKAGE_NOT_FOUND: SDK package not found by location: C:\Users\folsz\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator.

```
    More details for this error may be available online:
    
            https://github.com/ionic-team/native-run/wiki/Android-Errors
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable. I set it to the same value as `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` (`$HOME/Android/Sdk`) and the problem goes away.